# Error installing mpi4py

Tags: python, mpich, mpi4py

I'm trying to install mpi4py and have followed the installation instructions using pip found here: http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/install.html#using-pip-or-easy-install

I'm running a virtualenv with python 2.7.10 on Mac OS 10.11.6, and have installed mpich3 using homebrew.

This is the error when I attempt to run a test:

```
Lorens-MBP:mpi4py-mpi4py-b9fccf29258a lorensheets$ ../bin/python test/runtests.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/runtests.py", line 257, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "test/runtests.py", line 244, in main
    package = import_package(options, pkgname)
  File "test/runtests.py", line 109, in import_package
    import mpi4py.MPI
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/lorensheets/Desktop/fresh/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpi4py/MPI.so, 2): Library not loaded: /

Users/lorensheets/opt/usr/local/lib/libmpi.20.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/lorensheets/Desktop/fresh/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpi4py/MPI.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Does `/Users/lorensheets/Desktop/fresh/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpi4py/MPI.so` exist?

Comment: Yes, that file exists. This one does not however: `Users/lorensheets/opt/usr/local/lib/libmpi.20.dylib`

Answer (score -1):

Try installing openmpi instead of mpich3