# Unable to install mpi4py in MacBook M1

Tags: python-3.x, installation, mpi, openmpi, mpi4py

I am trying to install mpi4py in MacBook M1. I am learning MPI and I wanted to test a basic "hello world" python program on my machine. However, I am facing difficulty installing mpi4py. I have tried solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39213142/installing-mpi4py), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46674330/error-installing-mpi4py) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440834/error-when-installing-mpi4py) answers. Below is the entire error message I get in the terminal:

```
Collecting mpi4py   Using cached mpi4py-3.1.3.tar.gz (2.5 MB)   Installing build dependencies ... done   Getting requirements to build wheel ... done   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done Building wheels for collected packages: mpi4py   Building wheel for mpi4py (pyproject.toml) ... error   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
     × Building wheel for mpi4py (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> [156 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_src
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/run.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/bench.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/_base.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/server.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/_core.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/aplus.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/_lib.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/pkl5.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/dtlib.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/py.typed -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/__main__.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/run.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/bench.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/MPI.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/dl.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/libmpi.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/MPI.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/include
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.MPI.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.MPI_api.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.i -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/__main__.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/_core.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/aplus.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/server.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/pool.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/_lib.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/util/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/dtlib.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/pkl5.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/util
      running build_clib
      MPI configuration: [mpi] from 'mpi.cfg'
      MPI C compiler:    /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc
      MPI C++ compiler:  /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicxx
      MPI F compiler:    /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpifort
      MPI F90 compiler:  /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpif90
      MPI F77 compiler:  /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpif77
      checking for library 'lmpe' ...
      /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -c _configtest.c -o
_configtest.o
      /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      building 'mpe' dylib library
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/src
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/src/lib-pmpi
      /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -c src/lib-pmpi/mpe.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/src/lib-pmpi/mpe.o
      /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
      warning: build_clib: command '/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc' failed with exit code 127
      
      warning: build_clib: building optional library "mpe" failed
      
      checking for library 'vt-mpi' ...
      /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -c _configtest.c -o
_configtest.o
      /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      checking for library 'vt.mpi' ...
      /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -c _configtest.c -o
_configtest.o
      /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      building 'vt' dylib library
      /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -c src/lib-pmpi/vt.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/src/lib-pmpi/vt.o
      /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
      warning: build_clib: command '/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc' failed with exit code 127
      
      warning: build_clib: building optional library "vt" failed
      
      checking for library 'vt-mpi' ...
      /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -c _configtest.c -o
_configtest.o
      /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      checking for library 'vt.mpi' ...
      /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -c _configtest.c -o
_configtest.o
      /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      building 'vt-mpi' dylib library
      /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -c src/lib-pmpi/vt-mpi.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/src/lib-pmpi/vt-mpi.o
      /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
      warning: build_clib: command '/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc' failed with exit code 127
      
      warning: build_clib: building optional library "vt-mpi" failed
      
      checking for library 'vt-hyb' ...
      /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -c _configtest.c -o
_configtest.o
      /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      checking for library 'vt.ompi' ...
      /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -c _configtest.c -o
_configtest.o
      /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      building 'vt-hyb' dylib library
      /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -c src/lib-pmpi/vt-hyb.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/src/lib-pmpi/vt-hyb.o
      /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
      warning: build_clib: command '/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc' failed with exit code 127
      
      warning: build_clib: building optional library "vt-hyb" failed
      
      running build_ext
      MPI configuration: [mpi] from 'mpi.cfg'
      MPI C compiler:    /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc
      MPI C++ compiler:  /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicxx
      MPI F compiler:    /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpifort
      MPI F90 compiler:  /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpif90
      MPI F77 compiler:  /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpif77
      checking for dlopen() availability ...
      checking for header 'dlfcn.h' ...
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64
-I/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64
-I/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9 -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      success!
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      success!
      checking for library 'dl' ...
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64
-I/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64
-I/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9 -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      clang -flat_namespace -undefined suppress _configtest.o -Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39 -ldl -o _configtest
      success!
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest
      checking for function 'dlopen' ...
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64
-I/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64
-I/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9 -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      clang _configtest.o -Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39 -ldl -o _configtest
      success!
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest
      building 'mpi4py.dl' extension
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64
-I/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1
-DHAVE_DLOPEN=1 -I/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9 -c src/dynload.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/src/dynload.o
      clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-rpath,/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/lib -L/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/lib -L/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath,/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/lib -L/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/lib build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/src/dynload.o
-Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39 -ldl -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/mpi4py/dl.cpython-39-darwin.so
      checking for MPI compile and link ...
      /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64
-I/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9 -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      /Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc: line 301: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      error: Cannot compile MPI programs. Check your configuration!!!
      [end of output]
     note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.   ERROR: Failed building wheel for mpi4py Failed to build mpi4py ERROR: Could not build wheels for mpi4py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have downloaded wheel and upgraded pip, but haven't had any luck. Could anyone please tell me where I may be going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `/Users/sindhuja/opt/anaconda3/bin/mpicc` is a wrapper that invokes the C compiler `x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang` under the hood. The name suggests this wrapper uses a compiler for x86_64 instead of (native) ARM64, and that looks suspicious to me. Are you using the latest `anaconda` release that features native support for M1? If you only want to try `mpi4py` on your laptop, you can consider using `brew`, it supports everything you need natively on M1.

Comment: Thank you so much! Brew install works. However, the installation does not reflect in my code editor. I believe it is a path issue.

Comment: IIRC, on M1, `brew` stuff in in `/opt/homebrew/bin`

Answer (score 2):

Try install using homebrew :

```bash
brew install mpi4py
```

Comment: works for me on a M2 box as well, thanks!

Comment: This will not work with other python packages installed using anaconda and pip, right?

Comment: Yes @Coddy it is independent on package managers, it will work.